# Existence of common sample space for random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables

Given two random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on probability spaces $(\Omega_1, \mathbb{F}_1, P_1)$ and $(\Omega_2, \mathbb{F}_2, P_2)$ respectively, when can we assume that $\Omega_1 = \Omega_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_1 = \mathbb{F}_2$? What if instead of two random variables we have an uncountably infinite family of random variables $(X_\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta}$?

Perhaps the question is ill-posed - my motivation comes from statistical applications where people often work with a random variable $X$ defined on a sample space $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$ and we then change the probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$ to modify the distribution of $X$, i.e. we have a family $(P_\theta)_{\theta \in \Theta}$ of probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$ and consider the behaviour of the push-forward of $P_\theta$ under $X$ when varying $\theta$. It seems strange to me that we are free to assume that given a set of distributions $\mathcal{D}$ on $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$ and $P_\theta$ such for each $D \in \mathcal{D}$ there exists $\theta$ such that the push-forward of $P_\theta$ under $X$ is $D$.

Comment: The answer is yes. There is  a much more general result called Kolmogorov's Existence Theorem or Kolmogorov's Consistency Theorem.

Comment: Kavi's comment is accurate. I just want to add that your example is *not* problematic at all. In that case you can literally just pick $\Omega=\mathbb{R}$, $X$ to be the identity and $P_{\theta}$ some parametrisation of $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Aha, thats a nice way of vieweing it! I don't quite see the relationship to the Kolmogorov Existence Theorem though?

Comment: @Lundborg Kavi's comment is relevant for your question about families of measures of arbitrary cardinality. If $(\mu_i)_{i\in I}$ is some family of measures on (say) $\mathbb{R}$ and I want a single probability space $(\Omega,P)$ and random variables $X_i$ such that $X_i(P)=\mu_i$, the natural thing to do is to take $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^I$ and $P$ to be the product measure of the $\mu_i$. Only question then is whether or not that measure is actually well-defined. This follows from the Consistency Theorem.